# CSS blend background with elements below

Tags: css, blending

Is there anyway to have a child element's background blend with the colour of the elements below it **without** using `mix-blend-mode` which isn't well enough supported at the moment (read: it's not supported by Chrome)?

The image below is a crude example of what I'm talking about:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

With the CSS

```
element{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(#greyscale);
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

You can make an image Black And White.

What I suggest to do is creating your background, then create a div with the same background and the CSS showed above so it'll be black and white.

You can then set the background-size and background-position attributes to move your div around and match the image below.

It should make the trick!

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgfxestr/).

Comment: Well it must be adjusted to fit your site, but at least it is a starting point ;)

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no way to do this with pure CSS but for people who might want a Javascript solution I've found that filtering the `background` of the child, setting the `background-size` to that of the parent and setting the `background-position` to the negative amounts the image is offset from the background you want to filter.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4mo4dx2/)

This does not account for any text or generally multiple backgrounds to be filtered.  And `mix-blend-mode` seems like the only think to wait for.